# How can we set the width of a dropdown in VSTO Ribbn XML

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ms-office, vsto, office-addins, ribbonx

In my VSTO 2013 Add-In for Office 2010, I am using a dropdown in Ribbon XML. The default width of the dropdown is twice the width of the items in the dropdown. How can I reduce the width? I don't see any option in the Ribbon XML tags for the dropdown that would set the appropriate width.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you none of the items don't have spaces in the beginning or end.

The Ribbon extensibility model doesn't provide any attribute or method for setting the width of the DropDown control. It is set automatically based on the items' width and parent ribbon group content.

You can read more about the Ribbon UI controls in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)